# How to access items defined in mapStateToProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a js file for a react app, that uses mapStateToProps, and contains these 2 functions:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        users: state.gf.users,
        employees: state.gf.employees,
    }
}

const EmployeeListFilter = () => {
    const getEmployees  = () => {
        let employees = this.props.employees
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (empId) {
            getEmployees()
        }
    }, [empId])
}
```

The function mapStateToProps works, I can put in a breakpoint and see that is gets the employee list fine.

How do I then access that employee list from within getEmployees? this.props.employees says 'this' is undefined.

Comment: You don't use `this` in arrow functions. Props are passed as a param to those functions, so `this.props.employees` would be just `({ employees }) => `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to pass the props in:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        users: state.gf.users,
        employees: state.gf.employees,
    }
}

const EmployeeListFilter = (props) => {
    const getEmployees  = () => {
        let employees = props.employees
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (empId) {
            getEmployees()
        }
    }, [empId])
}
```